# Custom and strange SATA behaviour on Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, firefox, ssd

I am experiencing strange behaviour on my new computer running Arch Linux. Everytime I open Firefox or Redlight app or some other application it doesn't behave as it should. For example sometimes pages opening in Mozilla Firefox results in a page crash and I need to restart computer once or couple of times in order to work as expected. I don't have this problem in Google Chrome. Downloads are always corrupted no matter of the browser I am using and with message network error or similar error related to network. This is heppening on almost every application and with random behaviour like program closes by itself. I have Kingston SSD 64GB and this is my main suspect. I also have another Samsung 200GB HDD, even if I store downloads on this HDD always results in interrupted and corrupted downloads. I have installed Windows 10 on this HDD and there everything is working as expected, and I also tried booting from live usb and there also downloads are corrupted. Tried reseting CMOS couple of times with no results. I am connected with Ethernet cable. I have enabled and checked fstrim timer and it's called once in a week. I need help for further investigation of this problem and maybe some suggestions for troubleshooting. Thank you
[Screenshot of Firefox Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEypu.png)

Specifications:

```
MOBO: Asus P5Q LGA 775
CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo E8400
RAM: 8GB DDR2
SSD: Kingston SSDNow 200 64GB
HDD: Samsung 200GB
```

uname -a:

```
Linux ArchLinux 4.16.13-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu May 31 23:29:29 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port (rev 02)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 1
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Port 2
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 6
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 90)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JIR (ICH10R) LPC Interface Controller
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) SATA AHCI Controller
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) SMBus Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT200b [GeForce GTX 275] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 Gigabit or Fast Ethernet (rev b0)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

lscpu

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              2
On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               23
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8400  @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:            10
CPU MHz:             2372.750
CPU max MHz:         3003.0000
CPU min MHz:         2003.0000
BogoMIPS:            6001.39
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0,1
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority dtherm
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: download a copy of a bootable memtest86+, burn a cd or flash an usb pen, run it and examine the reports for memory error.

Comment: First place to look is `dmesg` output and `syslog` contents to see if there are any errors. And I second testing the RAM.

Comment: I checked dmesg and there are no errors there. I will test RAM right now

Comment: I have run memtest, RAM seems OK.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a solution to my problem. While i was opening my computer for CMOS reset I found that two heatsinks were extremly hot. I think that one was Southbridge and another maybe Northbridge. I dissassembled the motherboard and changed thermal paste on them. For now the problem is fixed and the computer is running very good. Thanks everyone who tried to help me and all best.